# How do I plot in python a cone for which I have the vertex point, line that is the central axis and opening angle?

Tags: 3d, parametric, python

I managed to get the equation of a cone for which I have the vertex, opening angle and central axis which the cone must revolve around. A sample is attached below for which they get the equation of a cone given the initial parameters mentioned above. I have tried the meshgrid method where I get the equation in terms of z but there are so many NaNs and I don't get a cone. Does anyone know how to plot the final equation in the image below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfFmL.png).

[Equation of the cone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfFmL.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python

Comment: There is no angle with a cosine equal to $\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{6}}$

Comment: So the locus of the obtained equation is the empty set, that is there is no surface at all.

Comment: Sorry, cos(theta)^-1  = 4/sqrt(6) so cos(theta) = 4/sqrt(6) in the equation